# How to make color from the table Ruffini - Horner Algoritms?

Tags: tables, algorithms, code

I Have problem about to make the table ruffini- horner algoritms,and i take a code from this question [command for table Ruffini-Horners Algorithm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122699) ,

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ruffini}{mmmm}
 {% #1 = polynomial, #2 = divisor, #3 = middle row, #4 = result
  \franklin_ruffini:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\seq_new:N \l_franklin_temp_seq
\tl_new:N \l_franklin_scheme_tl
\int_new:N \l_franklin_degree_int
\cs_new_protected:Npn \franklin_ruffini:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
 {
  % Start the first row
\tl_set:Nn \l_franklin_scheme_tl { #2 & }
  % Split the list of coefficients
\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_franklin_temp_seq { , } { #1 }
  % Remember the number of columns
\int_set:Nn \l_franklin_degree_int { \seq_count:N \l_franklin_temp_seq }
  % Fill the first row
\tl_put_right:Nx \l_franklin_scheme_tl
   { \seq_use:Nnnn \l_franklin_temp_seq{&} { & } { & } }
  % End the first row and leave two empty places in the next
\tl_put_right:Nn \l_franklin_scheme_tl{\\&&}
  % Split the list of coefficients and fill the second row
\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_franklin_temp_seq{,}{#3}
\tl_put_right:Nx \l_franklin_scheme_tl
   { \seq_use:Nnnn \l_franklin_temp_seq { & } { & } { & } }
  % End the second row
\tl_put_right:Nn \l_franklin_scheme_tl { \\ }
  % Compute the \cline command
\tl_put_right:Nx \l_franklin_scheme_tl
   {
    \exp_not:N \cline { 2-\int_to_arabic:n { \l_franklin_degree_int + 1 } }
   }
  % Leave an empty place in the third row (no rule either)
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_franklin_scheme_tl { \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & }

% Split and fill the third row
\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_franklin_temp_seq { , } { #4 }
\tl_put_right:Nx \l_franklin_scheme_tl
{ \seq_use:Nnnn \l_franklin_temp_seq { & } { & } { & } }
% Start the array (with \use:x because the array package
% doesn't expand the argument)
\use:x
{
\exp_not:n { \begin{array} } { r | *{\int_use:N \l_franklin_degree_int} { r } }
}
% Body of the array and finish
\tl_use:N \l_franklin_scheme_tl
\end{array}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\[
\ruffini{1,-6,11,-6}{2}{2,-8,6}{1,-4,3,0}
\]
\end{document}
```

I get error like this

[accidentally removed by author's edit, but a test run of the new code now gives

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \seq_count:N 
                        \l_franklin_temp_seq 
l.55 \ruffini{1,-6,11,-6}{2}{2,-8,6}{1,-4,3,0}
```

]

This is what I want:

[image]
Can you help me ?

Please..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a copy-paste error

Comment: Ouw ... this is my fault and about copy -paste error, i am sorry....

Comment: No problem! It happens! You got your code right almost instantaneously and the vote for closing is not a judgment on you, but only to the fact that this question will not be helpful to future readers. Keep on asking (and answering)!

Comment: i restored the links that were lost in the original edit, except for the error message, which has changed.  this may still be a copy-paste error; i'm not an `xparse` user, so am shaky on that ground.

Comment: Ok @barbarabeeton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You somehow manage to copy text, that gets malformed than.

Remove this:

```
% Split and fill the third row
\seq_set_split:
```

And you will be able to compile it.